# query to search with three keys with join query, where and like clause

Tags: join, sql-like

I'm doing a search operation in backend, so I have tried a query for it.My requirement is the user can search with (ip,instance name ,vm name)-with any of these three if he/she search , they should get the vm name.These are related to 4 tables and my query is:

```
 <pre>select cim.name as vm 
from ci_master cim 
     join
     ci_attribute_values  cav on cim.id = cav.ci_master_id
     join 
     ci_attributes cia on cav.ci_attributes_id=cia.id 
     join
     ci_category_master ccm on cim.ci_category_master_id=ccm.id 
where ccm.name='Virtual Machine'
  and ((cia.name='IP') or (cia.name='Instance Name'))
  and cim.name like 'comm%';

select distinct concat(cim.name,',',cav.ci_attribute_value) as vm
from ci_master cim 
     join
     ci_attribute_values  cav on cim.id = cav.ci_master_id 
     join
     ci_attributes cia on cav.ci_attributes_id=cia.id 
     join
     ci_category_master ccm on cim.ci_category_master_id=ccm.id 
where ccm.name='Virtual Machine' 
  and cia.name in ('IP','Instance Name')
  and ((cim.name) or (cav.ci_attribute_value) like '%comm%');

select distinct concat(cim.name,',',cav.ci_attribute_value) as vm 
  from ci_master cim 
       join
       ci_attribute_values  cav on cim.id = cav.ci_master_id 
       join
       ci_attributes cia on cav.ci_attributes_id=cia.id 
       join
       ci_category_master ccm on cim.ci_category_master_id=ccm.id 
where ccm.name='Virtual Machine'
  and cia.name in ('IP','Instance Name')
  and ((cim.name) or (cav.ci_attribute_value) like '%comm%');
</pre>
```

I have tried all these queries, but din't arrive at proper solution.

Comment: I formatted.If you do know , help me out.